# VBA Initialize and use arrays inside user-defined Type

Tags: vba, types

[VBA]
I have user defined types, as

```
Public Type XML_Comment
     LineNum            As Long
     CommentLine()      As String
End Type

Public Type XML_Attribute
    AttributeName       As String
    AttributeValue      As String
End Type

Public Type XML_Element
     LineNum            As Long
     PrettyPrint        As Integer
     ElementName        As String
     ElementValue       As String
     ElementAttribute() As XML_Attribute
     Comment            As XML_Comment
End Type
```

However, when I do use them in another module, I do get an out of range error, while the other element works

```
    With myXmlElement
        .ElementName = "name"
        .ElementValue = "Nick"
' ERROR Subscript out of range:
'        ReDim Preserve .Comment.CommentLine(UBound(.Comment.CommentLine) + 1)
'        .Comment.CommentLine(UBound(.Comment.CommentLine)) = "nice"
    End With
    
' This other case works
    Dim myArray(3, 2)  As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    myArray(1, 1) = "first"
    myArray(1, 2) = "1"
    myArray(2, 1) = "second"
    myArray(2, 2) = "2"
    myArray(3, 1) = "third"
    myArray(3, 2) = "3"
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
        With myXmlElement
            ReDim Preserve .ElementAttribute(i)
            .ElementAttribute(i).AttributeName = myArray(i, 1)
            .ElementAttribute(i).AttributeValue = myArray(i, 2)
        End With
    Next
```

Could you assist me in my effort to populate myXmlElement as per above ? Every help is appreciated.

Comment: `CommentLine` has no `UBound`. One option is to size it: `CommentLine(0 to 1)      As String`. Btw `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, actually I don't know how many values will I store in it, here as an example I just used one, but, indeed, the UBound doesn't work...

Comment: @BigBen Noted on your comment on the ReDim Preserve, will try to avoid it as per your advice by measuring before-hand the size needed.. Thank you very much.